# Passing a shell variable to inline python in a shell script

Tags: python, shell

I have a simple shell script where i want to be able to pass variables to some inline python i will write. For example like this

```
funny=879
echo $funny
python -c "
print(f"hello {$funny}")
"
```

However this prints

```
879
  File "<string>", line 2
    print(fhello
               ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
(pipeline) $
```

Any thoughts on what i could be doing wrong? I know i am setting the variable correct because when i do echo it prints out the variable so it is definitely set correct but for some reason python script is not able to use it.

Comment: Never try to use interpolation to build a script, whether it be SQL, Python, or any other language.

Comment: just curious why?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're using outer double quotes.

```
python -c "print(f"hello {$funny}")"
```

Gets turned into:

```
python -c print(fhello {879})
```

So python is passed 2 separate strings.

The inner double quotes would need to be escaped in order to get passed through to python.

```
$ funny=879; python3 -c "print(f\"hello $funny\")"
hello 879
```

Instead of messing around with quoting - if you export your variables you can access them from python using the [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) dict.

```
$ export funny=879; python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["funny"])'
879
```

You can use the `var=value command` syntax and omit the `export` (note the lack of a semicolon)

```
$ funny=879 fonny=978 python3 -c 'import os; print(os.environ["funny"], os.environ["fonny"])'
879 978
```

Comment: You can also pass an argument to the script: `python3 -c 'import sys; print(f"hello {sys.argv[1]}")' "$funny"`